# What can I do to fix this fireplace?

Tags: fireplace

House was built in the 1920's and has a brick fireplace that has been converted to ventless propane gas logs.  The logs work great but I haven't been able to use them because it gets so hot inside the "box" that the brick inner walls are black and outside, the heat goes straight up.  The exterior of the fireplace is wood and you can see that the heat is causing peeling and soot, almost a burned look on the outside.  Any ideas on how to fix this problem without having to put in a new insert?[image: picture of fireplace]

Comment: I wouldn't expect nearly that much soot from a gas log.

Comment: ...something is **deeply wrong here.** Have a service person from your propane vendor make a visit.

Comment: Soot in this case is caused by improper log placement.  It should be clean burning.  If soot is being produced then so is Carbon Monoxide.  Stop using, seek fireplace professional.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind having a glass screen in front of it, you could do that to prevent some of the heat from reaching the wood. Also cleaning the chimney and flume might help some more smoke escape